# Garbage char returned by Shell.StdOut.ReadAll

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, stdout

Here is my code

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

a = "@echo off && " & _
"pushd ""\\xxxxx.local\cfs\Development\Docs\Baseline"" &&" & _
"cls &&" & _
"dir /b /a-d &&" & _
"popd"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("%comspec% /c " & a)
execStdOut = objShell.StdOut.ReadAll()
msgbox execStdOut
```

Basically I am trying to run Dir command on a network drive. It works fine, but the only issue is that the output contains a garbage character in the beginning. Not sure why?

Output

[image]

If I run the same steps in a batch file, the output is correct

[image]

Comment: When you manually do `dir /b /a-d` on the directory containing Test-New_1.xml from the command line, what does the output look like? Are you getting anything weird in there?

Comment: No. In fact, when I use a batch file, the output is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is that `cls` is being captured by the `StdOut` stream and interpreted as an extended character.  Get rid of it.  You don't need it.

Just so I feel like I've done something, here's the script rewritten as a batch + JScript hybrid.  Save it with a .bat extension if you want to mess with it.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="shell" (
    pushd "\\xxxxx.local\cfs\Development\Docs\Baseline"
    dir /b /a-d
    popd
    goto :EOF
)

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript

var oSH = WSH.CreateObject('Wscript.Shell'),
    proc = oSH.Exec("cmd /c " + WSH.ScriptFullName + " shell");

oSH.popup(proc.StdOut.ReadAll());
```

---

As an added bonus, here's the same thing with a lovely "ding" noise added.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="shell" (
    pushd "\\xxxxx.local\cfs\Development\Docs\Baseline"
    dir /b /a-d
    popd
    goto :EOF
)

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript

var oSH = WSH.CreateObject('Wscript.Shell'),
    noise = WSH.CreateObject('WMPlayer.OCX.7'),
    proc = oSH.Exec("cmd /c " + WSH.ScriptFullName + " shell");

with (noise) {
    URL = oSH.Environment('Process')('SYSTEMROOT') + '\\Media\\Windows Exclamation.wav';
    Controls.play();
}

oSH.popup(proc.StdOut.ReadAll());
```

Comment: Can't believe `cls` will actually put something. You learn everyday. Thanks.

Comment: +One for this phrase: "Just so I feel like I've done something"... **`;)`** And I like the "ding" too!

Answer (score 2):

The `♀` character is *ASCII control character* Line Feed `0x0A`, a residuum of CLI `cls` command. Just omit the `"cls &&" & _` line in your code as follows:

```
a = "@echo off && " & _
  "pushd ""\\xxxxx.local\cfs\Development\Docs\Baseline"" &&" & _
  "dir /b /a-d &&" & _
  "popd"
```